# Android lollipop ssl socket inputStream , extra data 0 bits packed in between buffer

Tags: java, android, sockets, ssl

I am trying to read a file from inputstream of an ssl socket connection and save it as a file . Below is the code that works for any device lower than the android 5.1.

```
    while (inputStream != null && !cancel
            && (count = inputStream.read(bufferData)) != -1) {

      downloadData +=bufferData.length;

      fileOutputStream.write(bufferData,0,count);

      int percentOfDownload = (int) ((downloadData * 100) / totalSize);

    }
```

In android lollipop , i get the file corrupted with extra data 0 bits packed in between buffer data resulting in a file with size bigger than the original file.

The size is usually 12/13 bytes larger than the original file.
This happens only on android 5.1 above.

Comment: The problem is that file streamed in all other android devices is ok, while in android 5.0.1 device its creating a corrupted file.

Answer (score 1):

```
downloadData += bufferData.length;
```

That should be

```
downloadData += count;
```

You're counting bytes you didn't receive.

The code you posted will not corrupt the file as sent. Possibly your sending code has a similar problem, i.e. not using the count in the `write()` method, unlike what you've done above, which is correct.

I don't see the point of testing `inputStream` for null.

Comment: inputstream !=null check is kept for handling sudden closing of socket. downloadData is just kept to count bytesand is not used for any of the write process.Problem is the code works smooth for all versions of android lower than lollipop and creates a corrupted file that is some bytes larger than the original file sent.

Comment: Sudden closure of the socket does not cause `inputStream` to magically become null. That case is to be correctly handled via a `catch` block. Your file corruption problem is caused by the sender, as I have stated.

Comment: hi again , i have not provided the full block of code , that has full handling of all sorts of try catch eventualities.have just posted the code that is causing problem. Any ideas.Socket is and ssl socket and problem faced only on samsung galaxy s4 , upgraded to android 5.0.1

Comment: I repeat, for the third time. The problem is at the other end. Post the sending code. *This* code will spend 99% of its time blocked in the `read()` call, and a close during the read will cause an exception, which you are already handling, so the `inputStream != null` test remains futile.

Comment: Ok found the issue the inputstream i am reading punches in string of old for every buffer reading.found out in a simple text file.

Comment: i.e. 'not using the count in the `write()` method'?